# running batch file to xcopy files across workgroup

Tags: batch-file

I run a Windows workgroup as my home network. My Server 2008 box executes backup batch files using xcopy via Task Scheduler. The backup drives are attached to the Server. The local one works fine.

But when I attempt to add the other workgroup machine's (it's XP) backup batch file to the Task Scheduler Library , it prompts me to add a login with which to execute it. But, it does not list the other machine in the Locations area, so I don't know how to specify that account. I use the same login values for both machines, but they're created locally on each machine. I have tried typing it in longhand but it fails with an error to check the Location.

I don't want the hassle of creating a domain just for this one task.

QUESTION: how can I do this in a workgroup setting?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enter the remote machine's login creds. In a workgroup, windows authentication amounts to if `Username` = `@username` and `Password` = `@password`, grant access.  The long way, `NetBIOS_name\Username` will break if name resolution fails.  In a workgroup that happens often.

The only time you have to specify the remote machine is if you don't have a username + password on the client machine that matches any accounts on the remote machine.